# Kentico v9 smart search not getting results from my home page

Tags: kentico

My home page is the root node, and consists of HTML editable text and repeaters. The page types used by the repeaters have been excluded from the smart search, but editable text isn't showing in results.

Currently my path is set to: /%

Everything else seems fine, i'm getting results that i expect (minus some url alias issues), but this has be stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas:

Have you used the correct Documents **index type**?

https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Defining+document+indexes

Have you selected the root page type as allowed content (probably CMS.Root)?

Is the Search Preview (located on the Search Index itself) showing the page?

David

Comment: I'm sure i am. I have other pages, my section landing pages, which are child nodes who content seems to be indexed fine. 

I have Page (menu item) (CMS.MenuItem) as one of the page types to index.

Comment: Is your root is of type CMS.MenuItem? Usually this is something like CMS.Root.

Comment: Bingo! i added CMS.Root, rebuild and it's working as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, checking for whether page type is included in the index is probably the first thing one should look out for while debugging for Search Index not returning specific page type results.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't think of cms.root, and i had cms.page. Live and learn :)